# Does CAN-SPAM apply for emails sent on behalf of users?

Tags: email

If there were a service/website that allowed a user to send invites to email addresses for the purpose of joining the user on the service/website, would that fall under the domain of the CAN-SPAM act?

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer as I don't know the ins and out's of that law, but as a programmer I'm accustomed to assuming any emails my systems send will be subject to spam laws unless specifically given a reason they aren't (for example if a user can enter their own smtp settings so that my system can send emails FROM the user themselves, that in theory could remove or reduce your liability)

Comment: Thanks, to be safe I'm implementing an unsubscribe feature.